# Using healpy.anafast on gamma ray maps

Tags: python, healpy

I have a gamma-ray maps (image with surface brightness) in fits format as also .hpx as output by the Aladin converter.

I wish to compute the angular power spectrum. How do I create a file readable by
`healpy.anafast`? 
I seem to be getting the data format wrong (`TypeErrors`).

One of the Gamma Ray images I tried was the Fermi Galactic Diffuse. The file
is a public LAT Galactic diffuse map named `gll_iem_v02_P6_V11_DIFFUSE.fit` on:

http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/data/access/lat/BackgroundModels.html

I have pasted the code below as I use it, but it is essentially the script called `plot_wmap_power_spectra` on [astroml](http://www.astroml.org/examples/datasets/plot_wmap_power_spectra.html):

```py
    """
    WMAP power spectrum analysis with HealPy
    ----------------------------------------

    This demonstrates how to plot and take a power spectrum of the WMAP data
    using healpy, the python wrapper for healpix.  Healpy is available for
    download at the `github site <https://github.com/healpy/healpy>`_
    """
    # Author: Jake VanderPlas <vanderplas@astro.washington.edu>
    # License: BSD
    #   The figure is an example from astroML: see http://astroML.github.com
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    # warning: due to a bug in healpy, importing it before pylab can cause
    #  a segmentation fault in some circumstances.
    import pylab
    import healpy as hp
    ###
    from astroML.datasets import fetch_wmap_temperatures
    ###

    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # Fetch the data
    ###
    wmap_unmasked = fetch_wmap_temperatures(masked=False)

    #PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap =           np.arange(hp.read_map('PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap.hpx[1]'))
    PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap =   hp.read_map('gll_iem_v02_p6_V11_DIFFUSE.fit',dtype=np.float,verbose=True)
    #PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap = hp.read_map('all.fits',dtype=np.float,verbose=True)
    #cl_out =  hp.read_cl('PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap.hpx',dtype=np.float)#,verbose=True)
    wmap_masked = fetch_wmap_temperatures(masked=True)
    ###
    white_noise = np.ma.asarray(np.random.normal(0, 0.062, wmap_masked.shape))
    len(cl_out)

    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # plot the unmasked map
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    #hp.mollview(wmap_unmasked, min=-1, max=1, title='Unmasked map',
    #            fig=1, unit=r'$\Delta$T (mK)')
    ########----------------
    ##hp.mollview(PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap, min=-1, max=1, title='Unmasked map',
    ##            fig=1, unit=r'$\Delta$T (mK)')
    ########----------------
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # plot the masked map
    #  filled() fills the masked regions with a null value.
    ########----------------
    #fig = plt.figure(2)
    #hp.mollview(wmap_masked.filled(), title='Masked map',
    #            fig=2, unit=r'$\Delta$T (mK)')

    ########----------------
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # compute and plot the power spectrum
    ########----------------
    #cl = hp.anafast(wmap_masked.filled(), lmax=1024)
    cl = hp.anafast(PredictedSurfaceFluxFromModelMap, lmax=1024)
    #cl = cl_out
    ########----------------
    ell = np.arange(len(cl))

    cl_white = hp.anafast(white_noise, lmax=1024)

    fig = plt.figure(3)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(ell, ell * (ell + 1) * cl,
       s=4, c='black', lw=0,
       label='data')
     ax.scatter(ell, ell * (ell + 1) * cl_white,
       s=4, c='gray', lw=0,
       label='white noise')

     ax.set_xlabel(r'$\ell$')
     ax.set_ylabel(r'$\ell(\ell+1)C_\ell$')
     ax.set_title('Angular Power (not mask corrected)')
     ax.legend(loc='upper right')
     ax.grid()
     ax.set_xlim(0, 1100)

     plt.show()
```

Comment: I checked `gll_iem_v02_p6_V11_DIFFUSE.fit`, it is NOT in HEALPix format, so you cannot use it directly. If you manage to convert it to HEALPix with Aladin, please post it online (figshare maybe?) and we can try with that.

Comment: The file I have is a .hpx file. I am not sure about figshare. I think the dropbox link should work for now. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m812luj8vdo47h1/gll_iem_v02_p6_V11_DIFFUSE.hpx

Answer (score 1):

[I have uploaded your map also to Figshare](http://figshare.com/articles/Fermi_LAT_Diffuse_galactic_Background_Model_in_HEALPix/855624), where is likely to be available in the future.

Once you have the map in HEALPix format, it is easy to just read it with `healpy`:

```py
import healpy as hp
m = hp.ma(hp.read_map("gll_iem_v02_p6_V11_DIFFUSE.hpx"))
```

Mask NaN pixels:

```py
m.mask = np.isnan(m)
```

Plot it:

```py
hp.mollview(m, min=-1e-5, max=1e-5, xsize=2000)
title("gll_iem_v02_p6_V11_DIFFUSE")
```

[image: Mollview]

Compute and plot the angular power spectrum:

```py
plt.loglog(hp.anafast(m))
```

[image: power spectrum]

See also a IPython notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/7553252